# Jetpack infinite scroll render - make different depending on post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, content, plugin-jetpack, infinite-scroll

I am currently working on a theme which has two post types - one is the normal "posts" post type, and the other is for portfolio posts - "mytheme_portfolio".

I am using JetPack's infinite scroll to render new posts, as follows:

```
function mytheme_render_infinite_scroll() {
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content', 'archive-portfolio' );

    endwhile;
}

function mytheme_jetpack_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
        'container' => 'content',
        'type'  =>  'click',
        'render' => 'mytheme_render_infinite_scroll',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_jetpack_setup' );
```

This is working fine but I am wondering how I can specify different `content-` template files to render depending on the which post type's archive/category/tag page you are currently viewing. As it happens now I am calling `content-archive-portfolio.php` when the infinite scroll is triggered, what I would like is to call `content-archive-portfolio.php` if portfolio posts are being viewed, but `content.php` if the blog is being viewed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the above `mytheme_render_infinite_scroll` function with this:

```
function mytheme_render_infinite_scroll() {
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        if ('mytheme_portfolio' == get_post_type()) :
            get_template_part( 'content', 'archive-portfolio' );
        else :
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
        endif;
    endwhile;
}
```